# Optimize removing process complexity

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

when I have an Array and I want to remove one value from it I need to shift the next element to lift but the idea is to do shifting one time when a n of null value in array.

Comment: Okay? However I can't tell what exactly your question is. You might want to [edit] your post to add more information including an actual question.

Comment: Can you include more requirements, e.g. does the array need to keep its ordering? How should access be handled, e.g. if I remove the first element, what should subsequent access to index 0 return? Null or the element at index 1? Are you required to optimize removal of just a single element or would it be a couple of elements, i.e. could order of removal be important? Could removals be reordered?

Comment: reviwe the post i have edited it

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-array-deque

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is micro-optimisation, and `ArrayList` (maybe `LinkedList`) would be a production quality data structure for dynamic arrays.

Here you might keep an extra list of nulled entries. At a certain threshold one could do **`System.arraycopy`**s to remove the gaps. If there are many index  based inserts too, you might opt for keeping gaps, maybe collecting small gaps together.
This is a traditional technique in editors for text.

For several data structures one might search through guava classes.
For instance write-on-copy data structures.
Or concurrency, compactifying in the background.

For a specific data structure & algorithm maybe someone else can give pointers.